# Make images resize like a background image

Tags: html, css, image

I been looking everywhere, and I can recall I seen a solution to this before, but no luck in finding it back.
Is it possible to make images without a div around it, or being used as background, nevertheless scale like those?

Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="example-1.jpg" class="50-100">
    <img src="example-1.jpg" class="50-100">
    <img src="example-1.jpg" class="25-50">
    <img src="example-1.jpg" class="75-50">
</div>
```

How would I have to style the above images, to make them blocks of 50% width and 100% height(of width container, like one would do with padding-bottom for an image with backgound) for the first two and width: 25%, height 50% for the third and 75%/50% for the last?
This in such way the images are blocks, with the image itself cropped to fill the size.

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use a div with a background-image for each image?

Answer (score 1):

İ'm not sure, but you could use:

```
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
```